# Calling antiviruses from software to scan in-memory images

Tags: windows, security, antivirus

Our system periodically (several times a minute) calls an external service to download images. As security is a priority, we are performing various validations and checks on our proxy service, which interfaces with the external service.

One control we are looking into is anti-malware which is supposed to scan the incoming image and discard it if it contains malware. The problem is that our software does not persist the images (where they can be scanned the usual way) and instead holds them in an in-memory (RAM) cache for a period of time (due to the large volume of images).

Do modern antiviruses offer APIs that can be called by the software to scan a particular in-memory object? Does Windows offer a unified way to call this API across different antivirus vendors?

On a side note, does anybody have a notion of how this might affect performance?

Answer (score 0):

You should contact antivirus manufacturers - Some of them do, but you probably find it tricky to find out the pricing even.

Windows has [AMSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/amsi/antimalware-scan-interface-portal) which has a stream interface and a buffer interface. I am unaware if it makes a copy of the data in the buffer or scans the buffer as it is.

And it will absolutely wreck your performance, probably.

What might be faster would be to just have some code to assure that they are in fact images that can be read and re-encoded, but then there are obvious problems with re-encoding .jpg images, so maybe just sanity check the header and data with them. This could also be slower. decoding large images is slow, but it would probably catch 0 day exploits targeting libpng/libjpeg better.

Also you could read some horror stories of scanning servers like that being targets of malware in otherwise benign files, though the last one I remember is from last decade.